# set the data to dojo data grid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working with Dojo, and I have a small requirement. I am using a store to create a Memory. I have a hardcoded list so that I can set this list to a Dojo data grid store and thereby perform some rowclick functions. My issue is that I am not able to set the store, and I am getting an error, 
`this.headerContentNode.firstChild is null`. Please can anybody help me out?

the code snippet....

```
postCreate : function () {
  //publist, sublist etc
  this._handleLogDetails();
},
//methods...
_handleLogDetails : function(){

  alert("hello...h..");
  var theGreatestTeamOfAllTime = [ {
    "jobName":"12",
    "jobId":"Jim Kelly",
    "status":"QB",
    "timeStamp":"0"
  },
  {
    "jobName":"1",
    "jobId":" Kelly",
    "status":"B",
    "timeStamp":"10"
  }

];

var clientJobStore = this.jobModel.getLogStore();
clientJobStore.setData(theGreatestTeamOfAllTime);
var thisData = new ObjectStore({objectStore: clientJobStore});
this.dapJobStatusGrid1.setStore(thisData); // attach point of dojo data grid, getting an error at this point...
```

Comment: i need to see how you initialize the grid. also, a jsfiddle example would be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I just have a html datagrid, for that attach point iam setting this as u can see dapJobStatusGrid1 is the attachpoint of the data grid which is a static data grid in HTML

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert so not sure about this... but is theGreatestTeamOfAllTime out of scope when you try to use setData()?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly what the issue is here without seeing how the grid is configured, but this is likely caused by one of the following:

1. You didn't call startup() on your grid.
2. When constructing your grid, you did not provide a DOM node for the grid.

For example, perhaps try something like the following, where the second argument is the DOM node the grid should be attached to.

```
var options = {// some options};
var foo = new DataGrid(options, someContainer.domNode);
foo.startup();
```